# Visual studio detecting unused return

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I've just spent the best part of an hour trying to work out why some code appered to not be working. I was getting no compilation errors of any sort, and have tracked the bug down to calling a function and doing nothing with the return value. The code was a little more involved than the sample below as `Class1` is immutable, but it still demonstrates the issue:

```
public class Class1
{
    private int MyVal = 0;
    public int GetMyVal()
    {
        return MyVal;
    }
}

public void Tester(){
    Class1 Instance = new Class1();
    Instance.GetMyVal();
}
```

The function call to `GetMyVal()` is as technically useless as it is technically correct. As I say the code was more involved, but this is the core issue.

I'm slightly surprised that VS 2013 (For Web) fails to highlight the issue as clearly nothing is gained from calling GetMyVal. Is there some switches I'm missing to detect this sort of thing or is this beyond the scope of what Visual Studio can accomplish?

Comment: You'll need to look into something like FxCop or [Coverity](http://www.coverity.com/). However, both of those likely require a full version of VS 2013.

Comment: Are you expecting VS to analyze your code and make sure there are no side effects in calling `GetMyVal`?  I think that is out of the realm of what a compiler should do.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Thank you, I shall take a look.

Comment: It's worth it to look into Resharper by JetBrains, their tool really finds a lot of those conventions and highlights them whilst your are coding. (FxCop analyzes on build so is later to give you that information.) (Side note, Resharper does use some resources, it can eventually slow down VisualStudio if you are working in an older environment...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is/are (m)any editors out there can can give you what you want.

VS will tell you if you have a variable you're not referencing (at least for Pro and Ultimate. Haven't used Web for 2012/2013). However within the scope of Class1, `private int MyVal` **is** being referenced within your `GetMyVal` function so it will not be marked as an unreferenced property.

It can often catch useless pieces of code but I don't see how you expect it to say that your previously initialized **and** referenced variable is not meaningful. It has no way of knowing that the property in Class1 isn't something you want to use/modify later.

Do correct me if I am misunderstanding your question

Side note: If you can figure out a way to make it do what you're after,might I suggest writing a plugin? Bear in mind that existing plugins like Resharper and FXCop add a world of functionality

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. The issue isn't within the GetMyVal function, but rather I call the GetMyVal function that does nothing but return a value, and I just let the returned value drop into the ether. Hm, perhaps I am expecting a little too much…

Comment: Yeah, I think you're expecting a little too much from regular VS :) (for now anyway. MS has been pretty aggressive with awesome features recently). 

Tools like Resharper will alert you of the problem though [ eg: http://oi59.tinypic.com/2nstkwj.jpg ]. Unfortunately/Fortunately, it isn't a free tool.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help - that's the exact error as well I'd expect. :) I believe it's time to dust the cobwebs off the wallet. :)